# what compiler supports multi programming language?

Tags: c, visual-studio, delphi, visual-c++

i know it sounds crazy but, i just want to ask if is a compiler support multi programming language? like Delphi could also support C/C++/C# etc? if there is, please let me know. or how?

Comment: I would count a (i.e. "one") compiler supporting different languages (not flavours) a bad design. Besides that it would be a nightmare in maintenance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The GNU Compiler Collection includes
>   front ends for C, C++, Objective-C,
>   Fortran, Java, and Ada

http://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: It's called compiler collection and it's still a single compiler?

Comment: GCC is a bunch of binaries - front-ends, preprocessor, compiler and driver. You, as a user, only communicate with the driver, and it figures out the language (based on source file extension) and invokes appropriate front-end

Answer (score 5):

С++ Builder's projects can have both C++ and Pascal (Delphi) code in the same project. Just add existing or create a new .pas-file to C++ project. It will be compiled by C++ Builder (like it was C++ code).

The opposite is not true: Delphi can not compile C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

[Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) does C, C++ and Objective C.

Comment: Since both C++ and Objective-C are (non-strict) superset of C and C++ and ObjC can be mixed together (ObjC++), I consider it be only 1 language.

Comment: Hmm... but the semantics of C++ are very different.  It has to be a pretty flexible compiler to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Borland Rad Studio 2007 does C#, Delphi.NET, C++ (and with that also the C subset) and Delphi.

In later iterations, .NET support was abandoned.

But note that, like afaik GCC, these are in fact separate compiler binaries, with a common frontend that executes them.

Answer (score 1):

.net support multi-language programming (vc++, c#, vb, etc.)

Comment: But using one compiler per language, so that's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

GCC can be considered as unique compiler even though indeed it's made of several binaries... but you can call it always as gcc and supports C, C++, Objective-C and few more (a lot more indeed, theoretically: one language per available front-end).
At the beginning gcc meant GNU C Compiler, but then started to support more languages and the acronym became GNU Compiler Collection.

Answer (score 1):

LLVM is a new compiler toolset, with similar goals to GCC.